# error: no matching function for call to at c++

Tags: c++

I get this error in g++;

> error: no matching function for call to ‘CudnnRun::cudnnAddTensor_run(float [1][2][3][3], float [1][2][3][3], const int&, const int&, const int&)’

i wrote in cpp file, like this.

```cpp
const int mb_size = 1;
const int feature_num = 2;
const int in_size = 3;

float in_data[mb_size][feature_num][in_size][in_size] = {
   {
     { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 } },
     { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 } }
   }
  };
float out_data[mb_size][feature_num][in_size][in_size] = {
  {
    { { 3, 1, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 } },
    { { 10, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 } }
  }
};

CudnnRun m1;
m1.cudnnAddTensor_run(in_data,out_data,mb_size,feature_num,in_size);
```

in header file ,

```cpp
class CudnnRun
{
  public:
    void cudnnAddTensor_run(float *in_data,float *out_data,int mb_size,int feature_num,int in_size);
};
```

I intend to match the type of the argument of the function,Why does such an error occur?

Comment: What do you think the `float* ` means in the argument list?

Comment: Your `in_data` and `out_data` are `float ****` not `float *`

Comment: @AhmadWabbi no, `in_data` in the function prototype should be a `float (*in_data)[feature_num][in_size][in_size]`. That is what `in_data` in the calling function decays to.

Answer (score 1):

`in_data` and `out_data` are **four dimensional** data blocks! To that end, your initialisation statements look arbitrary to me.

Pointer decay at the function call site essentially collapses the outermost dimension. Bearing in mind that C++ does not support variable length arrays, your function prototype for the class member function needs to be

```
void cudnnAddTensor_run(
    float(*in_data)[1][2][3],
    float (*out_data)[1][2][3],
    int mb_size,
    int feature_num,
    int in_size
);
```

and the final 3 parameters appear to be redundant here.

Can you not reduce the problem to a single contiguous one dimensional array, and use clever indexing to get the element you want?